# Group array row on one column and form subarrays of varying depth/structure

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, grouping

I want to group rows in an array with the same `color` and then similar `size` data into special subarrays.

Sample array:

```
$array = [
    ['color'=>'#000000','size'=>'L','count'=>2],
    ['color'=>'#000000','size'=>'XL','count'=>1],
    ['color'=>'#ffffff','size'=>'L','count'=>2],
    ['color'=>'#ffffff','size'=>'XL','count'=>1],
    ['color'=>'#ff0000','size'=>'L','count'=>1]
];
```

And I want them to be like this `JSON`:

```
[{
   "color": "#000000",
   "size": [
      {
       "value": "L","count": 2
      },
      {
        "value": "Xl","count": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "color": "#ffffff",
    "size": [
      {
        "value": "L","count": 2
      },
      {
        "value": "Xl","count": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "color": "#ff0000",
    "size": "L",
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: Loop over it, and fill a new array with your data - using the `color` value as key on the top level, that helps with the "grouping". You can use `array_values` afterwards to "reset" those keys to a normal, zero-based index again.

Comment: The result in my answer, which you accepted, is different from the results you want in your question. Is my answer wrong, or was that a typo?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware that was typo ♥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Added a correction for the desired output at the bottom.

This seems easy, but is rather difficult to do right. The best approach is to divide and conquer. First collect the data together, which belongs together, and then make the nice JSON output. My first step is therefore this:

```
$input = [['color'=>'#000000','size'=>'L','count'=>2],
          ['color'=>'#000000','size'=>'XL','count'=>1],
          ['color'=>'#ffffff','size'=>'L','count'=>2],
          ['color'=>'#ffffff','size'=>'XL','count'=>1],
          ['color'=>'#ff0000','size'=>'L','count'=>1]];
          
$colors = [];

foreach ($input as $product) {
    extract($product);
    $colors[$color][$size] = $count;
}

echo json_encode($colors,  JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [#000000] => Array
        (
            [L] => 2
            [XL] => 1
        )

    [#ffffff] => Array
        (
            [L] => 2
            [XL] => 1
        )

    [#ff0000] => Array
        (
            [L] => 1
        )

)
```

Please note that [extract()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract) should be used with care, since it can generate more variables than you bargained for, but it is very useful here. Never use it at the global scope, like I did here.

And now we turn this into the wanted JSON, like this:

```
$output = [];

foreach ($colors as $color => $sizes) {
    $data = [];
    foreach ($sizes as $size => $count) {
        $data[] = ['value' => $size,
                   'count' => $count];
    }
    $output[] = ['color' => $color,
                 'size'  => $data];
}
          
echo json_encode($output,  JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This outputs:

```
[
    {
        "color": "#000000",
        "size": [
            {
                "value": "L",
                "count": 2
            },
            {
                "value": "XL",
                "count": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "size": [
            {
                "value": "L",
                "count": 2
            },
            {
                "value": "XL",
                "count": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "color": "#ff0000",
        "size": [
            {
                "value": "L",
                "count": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

You might want to put all this code inside a function.

Here's a [PHPFiddle](https://3v4l.org/ZTej1).

**NOTE: It is important to note that this code assumes that there are no duplicate color/size combinations in the input array.**

In case the output you want wasn't a result of a typo, here's how you can modify the second loop to get it:

```
$output = [];

foreach ($colors as $color => $sizes) {
    $data = [];
    foreach ($sizes as $size => $count) {
        $data[] = ['value' => $size,
                   'count' => $count];
    }
    if (count($data) == 1) {
        $output[] = ['color' => $color,
                     'size'  => $data[0]['value'],
                     'count' => $data[0]['count']];
    } else {
        $output[] = ['color' => $color,
                     'size'  => $data];
    }                     
}
          
echo json_encode($output,  JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

See this [PHPFiddle](https://3v4l.org/6f1ku)

Comment: The last element is not in the desired simple structure.

Comment: @mickmackusa : I agree, but that was probably a typo in the question.

Comment: I don't see anything to suggest that the asker is too incompetent to post what they actually want.

Comment: The `Json` structure provided in the answer is better than mine

Answer (score 1):

Iterate your array and establish associative fiest level keys based on the color values.

There are three conditional ways that each row's data must be stored to give your exact desired result.  There is no need to employ more than one loop.

1. When a color has never been encountered before, save the unchanged row with the new first level key.
2. On the second encounter of a given color, the structure must be adjusted to allow deeper subarrays.
3. After a given color has been encountered two or more times, the two values in the row can be pushed directly into the deeper subarray (size).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZFEnP)) ([with `extract()`](https://3v4l.org/NmYbj))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['color']])) {
        $result[$row['color']] = $row;
    } elseif (isset($result[$row['color']]['count'])) {
        $result[$row['color']]['size'] = [
            [
                'value' => $result[$row['color']]['size'],
                'count' => $result[$row['color']]['count']
            ],
            [
                'value' => $row['size'],
                'count' => $row['count']
            ]
        ];
        unset($result[$row['color']]['count']);
    } else {
        $result[$row['color']]['size'][] = [
            'value' => $row['size'],
            'count' => $row['count']
        ];
    }
}
echo json_encode(array_values($result), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: This does indeed produce the desired output, but only if that was indeed desired. Let's wait and see what the OP says.

Comment: I am surprised by your distrust of the asker.  I've never seen you this way before.

Comment: I guess I've seen too many sloppy questions on this platform. I shouldn't generalize though.

Answer (score -2):

Loop through the array and create a new array with a condition that meets it like this

```
foreach( $mixed_colors as $color ) 
{
    if($color->color == $color1) 
             { 

             $color1[] = array(
                 
                'color' => $color->color,
                'size' => $color->size,
                'count' => $color->count

                
                );
                
               
             }
                
    }
```

Then you put the arrays into another multi dimensional array.So the you will have arrays for all the colors, then you will put them into one array to have all the specific color arrays.